# Would the terminally ill Star Wars fan who was granted an early viewing of 'The Force Awakens' have been legally bound to keep the plot a secret?

Tags: contract-law

Since reading the news story about Disney and Lucasfilm granting a terminally ill Star Wars fan's wish to see the New Star Wars movie before he was taken by cancer (Good guys Disney and Lucasfilm!); I have been curious as to what the legal situation would have been surrounding watching such a closely guarded and long-awaited storyline before general release. Would he be contractually (or otherwise) obliged to keep all plotpoints to himself? Would the fact that he was terminally ill and not a film critic mean that this legal situation would differ from that which binds critics who see films before general release (assuming that critics are bound in any way)?

I must clarify I do not have a great knowledge of law so I'm not looking for fine detail specifics, but a layman explanation would be very interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel Fleetwood, and his wife who watched the movie with him, were bound [by a confidentiality agreement](http://m.tmz.com/#article/2015/11/05/star-wars-force-awakens-cancer-patient/):

> She can't say much more because she had to sign a confidentiality agreement.

Basically, both he and his wife signed a contract, if they had said anything they would have been in breach of that contract and could have been sued.

Such agreements are standard, even for actors, so presumably, the lawyers at Disney know what they are doing when they write such a contract. NDAs such as this often [specify hefty fines](http://www.theguardian.com/media/shortcuts/2014/oct/19/non-disclosure-agreement-arch-enemy-the-arts-critic).

I am doubtful that his illness would have meant they would have lost a case against him in that situation - it would have meant a whole lot of negative publicity, but if the contract was legally binding, the health condition does not matter.

Daniel himself [died five days after watching the movie](http://edition.cnn.com/2015/11/10/entertainment/dying-star-wars-fan-force-awakens-update/).